# How can I download web content using postman when I get a 403 error?

Tags: html, postman

I am trying to download a webpage using Postman from:

```
https://cookidoo.co.uk/recipes/recipe/en-GB/r252593
```

but I get a response from server as shown below and error 403 is quoted:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1>403 ERROR</H1>
    <H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    Bad request.
    We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
    configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
    <BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
    <BR clear="all">
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    <PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 4SL0NvJZt4eLt9GqQHw-RsgEJLVCpyY1n5zROPtiolExUJcup2J8Lw==
</PRE>
    <ADDRESS>
    </ADDRESS>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

I am not very familiar with postman or web technologies so any help would be gratefully received. I can download the page successfully in Safari. Am I missing some pertinent information in postman? Is it something to do with the website being a secure https site?

Answer (score 0):

Some headers/ cookies are missing.

To recreate a request from the browser in Postman, open the developer tools in the Browser (press F12).

Go to the Network tab, do a right click on the request you want to rebuild in Postman (in this case it's `r252593`) and select Copy/ Copy as cURL (bash).

[image: Copy cURL from browser]

In Postman, click the Import button, then select `Raw text`. Paste your clipboard (it contains the cURL copied in the browser) and click Continue.

[image: Import cURL in Postman]

This request in Postman returns the HTML of the page, it also has the same http status code (260) as the copied request in the browser:

[image: Request + result in Postman]

Comment: Thanks. I will remember those steps in the future

Comment: If this solved your issue, thanks for upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted a body that I was passing by mistake from another collection.